# how to avoid 'This field is required' when ForeignKey is set to 'self'?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_category = models.ForeingKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So when I am trying to create a new category in admin panel, django says "This field is required' and highlights parent_category: select field.
How to " explain" django, that it is the parent category and therefore no need to select parent_category?

please help.

Comment: Make it `null=True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `ForeignKey` is optional, you can make it NULLable. So then you insert `NULL`/`None` if a `Category` has no parent:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

Comment: here comes another question, then how can I make parent_category optional?

Comment: @VepaOrazov: by making it `null=True`, it is optional.

Comment: @VepaOrazov: you can set `blank=True` as well, to change how the form itself behaves.

Comment: Hoo-hoo, it works! Thank you Santa @Willem Van Onsem. Good luck and lot of money!